# How to solve jquery mistake

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have the following code which I found in [codeply](https://www.codeply.com/go/bp/132400). Copied it to visual studio. On snippets code looks just the way it should be, but on my computer I get this [image: Reality]. Why is this happening?  Also I get an error `script.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined at script.js:1` However I installed jquery, so I only get to wonder why the error occurs. Tried to install jquery another way with another links, but the error does not go away.

```js
$('.carousel[data-type="multi"] .item').each(function() {
    var next = $(this).next();
    if (!next.length) {
        next = $(this).siblings(':first');
    }
    next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        next = next.next();
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }

        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
    }
});
```

```css
.carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -100%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  100%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -100%; }
    .active > div { display:none; }
    .active > div:first-child { display:block; }

}
@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 992px ) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  50%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -50%; }
    .active > div { display:none; }
    .active > div:first-child { display:block; }
    .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
}
@media (min-width: 992px ) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -25%; }    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css" /> -->
    
    <!-- <script src="assets/script.js"></script> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src='Untitled-1.js'></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='Untitled-1.css'/>


</head>

<body>

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center"><h3>Product Carousel</h3></div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="3000" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e499e4/fff&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/e477e4/fff&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/eeeeee&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/500/f4f4f4&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code snippet, you have a reference to script.js, but it is commented out.

```
<!-- <script src="assets/script.js"></script> -->
```

Yet, that's where the error message you posted shows there is a ReferenceError.

If you have script.js enabled / uncommented in your actual test code, and everything is listed in the order you posted, then that is likely your problem. If you are using jQuery in that JavaScript file (i.e. script.js), then put the "script.js" script tag below all of the other script tags (especially, at least, your jquery.min.js tag).

In your code snippet above, you have it listed first, and if it's included before jQuery (and you are trying to use jQuery in script.js) then $ will not yet be defined as your error message reads.